# Investigating why realism feels off

Tags: cycles-render-engine, photorealism

I'm trying to create a realistic looking chess board. I don't have a picture to compare it to, I'm just improvising.
However after rendering it feels "off" and being a noob I don't have the experience to pinpoint what is causing this impression.
Can anyone give some pointers on the usual sources of "non realism" to look for?
I know this is very broad but I'm hopping there is some common causes that should be investigated first in that kind of situations.

[image]

Comment: `I don't have a picture to compare it to` Maybe start from there. Gather some references. Not just one; many, for different things, may it be color arrangement, texture believability, composition, lighting whatever. And pinpoint from them what you are missing in your render. There are good reasons why pros work from reference all the time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two broad classes of 'realistic' photographs: product photography and everything else.  Your render appears to be an attempt to mimic product photography and I suspect you didn't intend it to be. There are two main differences: product photography is meant to highlight a product against a background and strives for perfection in the image, that is no dirt, no wear, et cetera; while other photography strives to tell a story.  But there are common elements from the point of view of realism.

Your chess board doesn't look credible. Thake a look at some commercial products.  The board is always framed by a boarder that's roughly as thick as one of the pieces.  It's also usually thinner top-to-bottom then your board.  The round over on the edges is usually more pronounced.

Glass chess pieces are very difficult to photograph and I'd recommend using a solid white until you got an image you like.  Then you can experiment with making the glass work.

The rook's top bits seem thin, but check a real set in the style you're interested in.  The bishop's face pieces are obscured, making it hard to tell if they have the usual slot. Otherwise the set seems to be well proportioned.

For a product photograph the wood is too busy. It draws the eye away from the product.  Product photos almost always have simple backgrounds.

Reconsider your lighting.  For a product shot, diffuse lighting is often more common than spot, and the vignette effect is a bit much.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Do you want even lighting to display the product clearly or do you want to focus on a specific piece as an example of the craftmanship?

For a non-product photograph, you probably don't have set dressers making sure that the set is spotless and hand selecting the pieces and board so that they have no wear.  You did a good job of making sure that the pieces weren't aligned too accurately, but perhaps the forward white knight might be angled a bit towards the center? But you could use a bit more wear. The edge of the board border would be a good place.  If the board is more worn but the pieces are much cleaner it tells a story about how much the user cares about each, for example.

Also, a non-product photograph should tell a story.  If you're going to use such a tight focus on the board, then you have to make the positions of the pieces work for you.  Why is this position interesting?  It's a pretty common opening. Maybe a different position later in the game?  Something that tells of a long battle between two styles?  Even non-players will see the configuration and thing something has happened.

Back to lighting: Even in a tight focus, so many shiny objects would reflect many things.  an HDR can be very helpful here; especially a credible interior HDR.

Answer (score 7):

I think one of the biggest problems with this (in terms of photorealism) is that it looks too perfect. Perfection is a telltale sign of CGI as opposed to a real photograph.

You can fix this by adding surface imperfections such as fingerprints, polish streaks, maybe some damage or dirt and dust or something.

The wooden tabletop surface looks too flat. It needs a bump or normal map to bring out that wood grain. In a pinch, you can just use the image texture as a bump map but a good texture would have come shipped with normal and roughness maps.

Same applies to your chessboard. Textures with marble or woodgrain-like appearances rarely have uniform roughness or a perfectly flat surface. You can't see too many reflections on the chessboard but it's worth consideration.

The spotlight isolates the chessboard and draws the eye to the focal point, but in the real world, you rarely get this kind of setup. Think about what kind of room this is in and consider what the lighting setup of that room would look like. Make it feel less like this 'photo' was taken in a studio.

A commenter suggested looking at real photos - which is a great tip as well.

Other than that, I think the scene is too empty. It needs one or two more props - some books, a light (or candle) or something. Maybe some paper or a coaster with ring stains on it or something. Think about other things that might accompany your chessboard on or around the table.

Comment: FWIW, most commercial photographers would disagree with the first paragraph, although most CGI artists would strongly support it.  Product photography is, in the large, about faking perfection.  If we can't do it in camera, we fix in post, using retouching techniques that date back to the early days of negative "fixing".

Comment: True enough @MartyFouts. Some experts and commentators remark at the irony that professional photographers chase perfection, while CGI artists do the opposite and expend effort on making things less perfect. It's especially true in product photography, but I'd wager that it's less so with more candid or on-location shots.

Answer (score 6):

Beyond the other advice on this page (which is all very good) you should work on making the Blender camera behave more like a real camera.  Things like depth of field and a very slight fish-eye to replicate some lens distortion will go a long way here.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are either using a very long focal length or parallel projection. Make sure to have a wider FOV, try setting the camera to 35mm focal length.
You have only one light roughly at the camera position, this is not very realistic. Make sure you actually have some background light, ideally by using a 360° image as background. If you do that right, you don't need any discrete lights in your scene. If you add lights, make sure you use area lights and not point lights. Don't just use white light - experiment with different color temperatures.

Make sure all the concave parts and silhouettes of your objects are tesselated well enough and don't rely on normal maps for structural features.
Never have sharp edges - make use of the bevel modifier.

If you have multiple instances of the same object, make sure to rotate each instance or shift the texture coordinates enough to make them look different.

Add some deliberate damage to your geometry, such as chipped edges.

Don't just dial in fixed values on the material properties but rather use textures that contain some slight variations for all the parameters (you can find material libraries for free on the internet).

For very uneven surfaces, use displacement maps instead of normal maps.

Use PBR materials.
Make use of subsurface scattering, especially for materials like marble, skin, plastic.
Enable depth of field and choose an interesting focal point. Add some slight lens flares.
Add some slight fisheye distortion in post.
Use the cycles renderer.

Render a higher resolution image than you need and downsample with a high quality filter.